# How to properly create two entities with cyclic dependency?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

If I have two entities, `Parent` and `Child`, `Parent` needs to know about all of its `Child` children, and every `Child` instance needs to know about its parent `Parent` instance, how do I do this properly (in terms of DDD etc)?

The easy way would be to do `parent.addChild(new Child(parent))`, but this seems ugly - as well as:

```
parent.addChild(new Child()); // Then call some setParent method on child, which needs to be public
```

Do I need to use a factory here? And if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to have a relevant instance method on the Parent class. A static Factory is probably not necessary here since you are operating on existing objects and simply need to connect object with another.

```
public class Parent {

    // ...

    public Child createChild() {
        Child c = new Child(this);
        this.addChild(c);
        return c;
    }

    protected void addChild(c) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

}

public class Child {

    public Child(Parent p) {
        // ...
        this.addParent(p);
    }

    protected addParent(Parent p) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If the Child constructor needs arguments, you can pass those to the `createChild` method.

Comment: Yes, but this would still expose the "parent setter" to any other objects that would like to create a child. My point is that only a parent should be able to set the parent of a child. Is this an unreasonable requirement? Or would it add too much overhead/complexity?

Comment: @Piotr: That's the point when you need to make Parent and Child more deeply aware of each other. In Java, you'd do this by putting them in the same package. In C++, they'd have friend-only access to each other. (I know there must be an equivalent in C# but I don't know it.)

Comment: If you goal is to hide parent setter you can go for SWT-like constructor-based child creation.

Comment: @Donal Fellows great point. Perhaps I should consider putting them in the same package. Thanks for the input

Comment: @Piotr Blasiak: In that case, you'd need to pass the parent to the Child's constructor and change the visibility of the "addParent" method to protected or private. I updated my sample.

Answer (score 2):

You are not limited to a single one approach. You should use the approach that fits you.

In SWT the child is linked to parent in constructor:

```
new Label(parentComposite, SWT.NONE);
```

After that parentComposite knows its child.

Note: SWT requires parent on creation which limits some functionality - you can't create child without specifying a child. This is limitation of the SWT.

In Swing you can create child widget and then add it to the parent.

Those above just the examples. Your personal solution will be based on your needs.

I would consider to use less methods, more consistency (don't leave your childs unlinked from parent)

Talking about code I would use following method:

```
Parent {
 addChild(Child child) {
  children.add(child);
  child.setParent(this);
 }
}
```

Hope that helps. Happy designing!

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you please check Sauls answer and my comment on it and comment?

Answer (score 2):

How about to do something like this:

```
public class Child {
   Child (Parent parent) {
      ... 
      this.parent = parent;
      parent.addChild(this);
   }
}
```

So you can set parent to Child only while creating child.